# Snakemake wrappers fails to open environment file: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: snakemake

When using snakemake wrappers with snakemake version 5.5.2 like this:

```
rule bcf_to_vcf:
    input:
        "{prefix}.bcf"
    output:
        "{prefix}.vcf"
    params:
        ""  # optional parameters for bcftools view (except -o)
    wrapper:
        "0.38.1/bio/bcftools/view"
```

I get the following error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
WorkflowError:
Failed to open environment file https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/0.38.1/bio/bcftools/view/environment.yaml:
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Apparently, the wrapper files are no longer available on bitbucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL/DR:

To use **snakemake-wrappers** version `0.38.1` and above, you need to use **snakemake** version `5.7.0` or higher.

#### What is going on:

Snakemake (and snakemake-wrappers) recently migrated from bitbucket to Github. This causes some minor inconvenience with the paths to the snakemake-wrappers repository used internally by snakemake. The easiest way to solve this is to update snakemake to version `5.7.0` or newer. These version already use the new paths to the Github version.

While the bitbucket repo of snakemake wrappers is still online, it only contains the snakemake-wrapper versions `0.38.0` and lower. To use a higher version of snakemake-wrappers (as `0.38.1` in the code above), you need a newer version of snakemake, which pulls workflow data from the Github version of snakemake-wrappers repo.